# What is Unicode?

Tags: unicode, ascii

I am a complete novice to using LaTeX and have begun with overleaf online and noticed one of the first lines run in the source code is `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

I understand this is to run a Unicode, but I don't understand what this means, from Google searches I have found it to mean a 'universal character representation standard for text in computer processing' and 'it provides a consistent way of encoding multilingual plain text making it easier to exchange text files internationally'. However, I don't really understand this. Is there a way to break it down into a simpler explanation, so I know what this code is whenever I see it?

Also, I have seen that Unicode and ASCII are character encoding standards, can someone please explain what an encoding standard is to me as well?

Comment: The definition of an encoding is completely unrelated to LaTeX. If you want the defintion of a character encoding, you should post this elsewhere, like Stack Overflow. A question here should be about, for example, using an encoding in LaTeX.

Comment: Simply put: Your computer has no idea about letters, it only knows numbers, so each letter is assigned to a number. In ASCII this assignment table is rather small (only 128 characters, if you use extended ASCIIs 256). That's not nearly enough for all the different characters there are. So Unicode was born to describe a lot more characters using numbers. The alpha-numeric ones stayed the way they are in ASCII, but umlauts, non-Latin characters etc. are encoded by multiple consecutive bytes.

Comment: note that in a current LaTeX `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is no longer needed as utf8 is the default file encoding anyway.

Comment: unicode has a home page: https://home.unicode.org. But unicode is not the same as utf8.  Unicode assigns every character a number, a codepoint, while utf8 describes how such codepoints are encoded in a file. See e.g. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e4/index.htm for various representations of a unicode character like ä.

Comment: note Unicode is a name, so you don't have "a unicode"  there is just one standard. It is also the standard used on this web page. The fact that you see a letter e here "e" is due to the page having  byte 101 (hex 0x65) which is the UTF-8 represesntation of a letter e.

Comment: Suggested read (he says it's for developers, but it's for everybody): https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, Overleaf uses UTF-8 for its files, so the line

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

can be omitted, because UTF-8 input has been the default in LaTeX for a few years.

A file in a computer is simply a sequence of bytes, that is, 8-bit numbers, which means from 0 up to 255.

When you open a file with a text editor, the machine interprets those numbers as characters according to an encoding that the text editor announces to the operating system.

There are many such encodings, which all extend the legacy ASCII 7-bit encoding, but in incompatible ways.

In the late 80's of last century, people realized that this plethora of encodings isn't the best way to cope with the problem of storing and interchanging text files, so a 21-bit encoding was devised and named Unicode. On the other hand, storing a text file as a sequence of 21-bit numbers is very inconvenient, because it would pump up the size of most files by a factor 3. Think to the thousands of configuration files sitting in the file system that are needed when you fire up the machine or an application.

Character sets for many scripts were already beyond the 256 limit posed by 8-bit encodings and, for instance, the Japanese had already devised multibyte encodings for their very large character set: the first attempts used two bytes to encode a character, so the available slots were 65536. But this is too small! You can't encode two ideographic scripts at the same time and moreover, there are so many scripts used around the world.

But, as I said, using 21 bits to encode a character is inconvenient, so a different way to represent Unicode has been introduced and called UTF-8.

Unicode characters are represented by 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes. The 1-byte characters are those of the legacy ASCII encoding. When the machine finds a byte from 128 to 255, it interprets it as a prefix that first tells how many more bytes to read in order to get a Unicode character; the two, three or four bytes together correspond to a Unicode character according to some not so complex rules.

Note that not all bytes from 128 to 255 are legal prefixes, but this is not relevant to the discussion.

TeX (the original and `pdftex`) doesn't know about encodings. It knows ASCII and that's all. But it can be programmed to interpret the higher range of bytes (128–255) so to accommodate the various legacy encodings *including* UTF-8.

Until a few years ago, you had to announce LaTeX what encoding the file was supposed to be saved in. Then it was decided by the team that times were mature to make UTF-8 the default encoding. So now you need to load `inputenc` only if the file to be processed is *not* UTF-8.